# What does the double vertical line (‖) mean in this dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

[The Williams' Dictionary of the Māori Language](http://www.nzetc.org/tm/scholarly/tei-WillDict.html) uses the symbol ‖ to denote words connected to other words.

[In this example](http://www.nzetc.org/tm/scholarly/tei-WillDict-t1-body-d1-d1.html#A.-iii), "ā" and "tā" are the plural and singular possessives respectively (ellipsis mine):

> **Ā** (iii). Plural of the definitive particle **tā** ... Ka kai ratou i reira, pau ana ā nga hoa, katikati tonu a Tama (T. 78). **‖ tā (iii)**.

[Whereas in this example](http://www.nzetc.org/tm/scholarly/tei-WillDict-t1-body-d1-d1.html#Auta.ne), autane is the brother-in-law of a woman, and taokete the sister-in-law of a woman, or brother-in-law of a man:

> **Autāne**, n. A woman's brother-in-law. **‖ taokete**.

[In this example](http://www.nzetc.org/tm/scholarly/tei-WillDict-t1-body-d1-d1.html#Awheto), awheto is a different pronunciation of awhato (a caterpillar which has been parasitised by a fungus, the charcoal of which was used as tattoo ink):

> **Awheto. ‖ awhato.**

It's unclear to me what specifically the double vertical line denotes in this context. Does it have a special meaning in the context of dictionaries, or translation dictionaries?

Comment: In Williams’ dictionary it definitely means “also see”, in other dictionaries it can mean something else, always consult the preliminary matter of a dictionary to find out its structure, abbreviations, and symbols.